# How to stop user module from printing password and salt in stdout?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I've been trying to learn Ansible so I apologize if this is something trivial but I haven't found anything about this searching around.

Whenever I run a task using "with_items", the stdout contains all the variables contained in those item. And when I use it with the builtin user or authorized_key modules, that includes password and salt.

Is there a way to NOT have it printout some of the items content? Ideally I'd like to just have the username so if it fails I'd know on which user, but I'd rather have no item printed out at all than having passwords and such in stdout :D

Verbosity for the Job Template is set to "0 (Normal)" that is the minimum I can set it to.

[image: STDOUT]

PS: I'm using latest AWX version installed with awx-operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [`loop_control: { label: "whatever" }`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label) is for, although be aware that at high enough verbosity it may still echo them